# Datadog RUM not loading V-icon in session replay

Tags: material-ui, vuetify.js, datadog, rum

Icons are displayed properly in the browser but when I try to replay the session via Session replay the icons are missing and icon-name is displayed.

Material icons are imported via CDN.

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined|Material+Icons+Two+Tone|Material+Icons+Round|Material+Icons+Sharp");
```

I'm using v-icons like:

```
<v-icon>keyboard_arrow_down</v-icon>
```

Datadog Rum init

```
datadogRum.init({
applicationId: 'xxx',
clientToken: 'xxx',
site: 'us3.datadoghq.com',
service:'xxx',
env:process.env.NODE_ENV,
sampleRate: 100,
trackInteractions: true,
defaultPrivacyLevel: 'allow'
});

datadogRum.startSessionReplayRecording();
```

What I expect to see in session replays:

[image]

What is actually rendered in session replays:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Per the docs](https://docs.datadoghq.com/real_user_monitoring/session_replay/#some-html-elements-are-not-visible-at-replay), web components are not supported in replay:

> Session Replay does not support the following HTML elements at the moment: iframe, video, audio, canvas, as well as Web Components.